# How do i find out in sql what db name I'm connected to

Tags: sql-server

We have a change control environment where the developers give scripts to change control people to run.  we have dev,qa, & production environments.

I want to conditionalize a couple segments to do some different things depending on what database the change control person is running my script.

```
If @dbname='dev'
then
begin
 --do some dev stuff
end
If @dbname='QA'
then
begin
 --do some qa stuff
end
If @dbname='Prod'
then
begin
 --do some production stuff
end
```

How do I get at what the current connected database is and fill @dbname?

Comment: This is okay (if a little suspect) at the DBA level, but if you're in the developer group this is pure evil - just don't do it.

Comment: The answers below give you the "how", but I agree with Joel. That's asking for trouble down the road.

Comment: it's for security mostly.  The db's are back refreshed from production.  Devs aren't allowed in production.  I programtically add the dev users in to qa and dev environs and the qa people in to qa environ as part of the scripts and don't touch security on the production environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's just like:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DBName
```

Answer (score 7):

`SELECT db_name()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Use the system function db_name()

```
Select db_Name()
```